# Google Cloud Storage - How to retrieve a file's owner via Python?

Tags: python, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to access to a blob uploaded on a bucket of Google Cloud Storage via Python official client (google-cloud-storage).
I'm managing into retrieving the owner of the file (the one who uploaded it), and I'm not finding something useful on internet.

I've tried using the client with something like:

```
client(project='project').get_bucket('bucket').get_blob('blob')
```

But the blob properties like "owner" are empty!

So I tried using a Cloud Function and accessing to event and context.
In the Google documentation (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource) it is reported the structure of an event and it seems to have the owner propriety. But when I print or try to access it I obtain an error because it is not set.

Can someone help me? I just need to have the user email... thanks in advance!

EDIT:

It doesn't seem to be a permission error, because I obtain the correct results testing the API from the Google site: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get?apix_params=%7B%22bucket%22%3A%22w3-dp-prod-technical-accounts%22%2C%22object%22%3A%22datagovernance.pw%22%2C%22projection%22%3A%22full%22%7D

Comment: Does the account that you use for retrieving object metadata have enough/right permissions?

Comment: Hi, yes, I've just verified and I have the right permissions, indeed if I test the Google API with the link in the description I obtain all metadata, even the owner

Comment: and just to make sure, you are using the same user, right? also is there ANY metadata associated or all of it is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, owner and ACL are not fetched by `get_blob`. You will have to explicitly fetch this info:

```py
blob = client(project='project').get_bucket('bucket').get_blob('blob')
blob.reload(projection='full')
```

Note that if you use [uniform bucket-level ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access) owner doesn't have any meaning and will be unset even with the above change.

EDIT: this is actually not the most efficient option because it makes an extra unnecessary call to GCS.  The most efficient option is:

```py
blob = Blob('bucket', 'blob')
blob.reload(projection='full', client=client)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this resolved my problem!!